# PHP7.1 + XDebug + WAMP + Visual Studio Code issues

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, wamp, xdebug, php-7.1

I've been trying to get a working setup for almost 2 days. Still no luck.

### The Problem:

In Visual Studio Code, in my project once I click the green arrow to 'Star Debugging', and then I go over to my browser with my local website, I refresh. Nothing happens in VSC. No Variables get listed, none of my Breakpoints do anything, etc.

### My Environment:

- Windows 10
- WAMP 3.1.3 32bit enviroment - located: `c:\wamp`
- vhost set up for my multiple website installations in WAMP `website-project-name:8080`
- Apache 2.4.27 using port `:8080`
- PHPv 7.1.16 32bit x86 - located 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.16'
- Visual Studio Code v1.21.1 w/ phpdebug installed
- Web projects location - `c:/wamp/www/[project-name]`

### XDebug setup:

XDebug shows as installed correctly in my php.ini file (used [this](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to confirm). Current settings I have set up for XDebug:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.16/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.1-vc14.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = on

xdebug.remote_autostart = on

xdebug.remote_connect_back = off

xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1

xdebug.remote_port = 8080

xdebug.remote_log="c:/wamp/bin/xdebug/xdebug.log"

xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

### VSC setup:

In VS, I have this as my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 8080,
            "pathMappings": {
                "wamp/www/totara-10.0": "c:/",
            }    
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I'm getting in my xdebug error logs is:

```
Log opened at 2018-04-02 16:19:22
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:8080.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/wamp/www/totara-10.0/theme/image.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.1.15-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="17712" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.6.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2018-04-02 16:19:22
```

I noticed the `fileuri` is showing `file:///`, but anything I change in VSC with my `pathMappings` shows up nothing changing. Assuming this is one big problem, can I can't see where to change this.

I have tried many different tweaks and even php versions. I have Google and followed multiple guides with no luck (one guy had issues on Windows and using a capitalized C:/). For the time I've put into this is ridiculous and makes me feel even more defeated.

Comment: `xdebug.remote_port = 8080` and `"port": 8080,` -- this is WRONG. RTM please. It's the port for XDEBUG to connect to client (VSCode in this case) and VSCode to listen on ... and NOT website port. Revert to default `9000` (or `9001` if you prefer .. so it's safe even on Linux/Mac) and it should do the job. Xdebug log clearly shows that it connected somewhere (Apache, in this case) and got told to go away (nicely speaking).

Comment: *"I noticed the fileuri is showing `file:///`"* That's correct -- Xdebug just tells what file was triggered the debug session/attempt. P.S. I'm not sure about correctness of your "pathMappings" (not VSC user myself) ... but considering that it's all on local system .. you may not need it at all. it's for mapping remote path (another computer) to the local one.

Comment: @LazyOne - Seriously??? Ok, when I updated this I get a `I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(`

Comment: @LazyOne - Edit: Got it to work! Forgot to un-comment my `xdebug.remote_host`. So exited to FINALLY see this working. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

I did not understand that the XDebug port needed to be different than the local Apache web port. Thought these were suppose to be the same.

Default port 9000 would not work however from IIS being installed, so just used 9001.

Changed 
`xdebug.remote_port = 9001`

and in Visual Studio Code
`"port": 9001`

Fixed the issue.